# associations - displaying name rather than the id in the views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, a Games model and a Platforms model.

In my Games table, I have a column called `platform_id` -- while in my Platforms table, I have a column called `system`

I tried to get the system to display in views using `<%= @game.platform_id.system %>` -- but it's not working.. what am I doing wrong? thanks in advance!

my models

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :platforms 
    has_one :genre  
end

class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :game
end
```

Games table

```
create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "image"
    t.date     "release_date"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "platform_id"
    t.integer  "genre_id"
  end
```

Platforms table

```
create_table "platforms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "system"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Games controller

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :set_game, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def index
        @games = Game.all
    end

    def show
        @reviews = Review.where(game_id: @game.id)
        @previews = Preview.where(game_id: @game.id)
        @news = News.where(game_id: @game.id)
    end

    def create
        @game = Game.new(game_params)
        @game.save
        redirect_to @game
    end

    def new
        @game = Game.new
        set_platforms
        set_genres
    end

    def edit
        set_platforms
        set_genres
    end

    def update
        @game.update(game_params)
        @game.save
        redirect_to @game
    end

    def destroy
        @game.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

private

    def game_params
       params.require(:game).permit(:title, :image, :release_date, :genre_id, :platform_id)
    end

    def set_game
        @game = Game.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_platforms
        @platforms = Platform.order(:system)
        @platform = Platform.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_genres
        @genres = Genre.order(:category)
    end

end
```

Comment: As per your associations you have wrong `FK`s. You should be having `game_id` in `platforms` table not `platform_id` in `games` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are designing it wrong. If you say that `Platform` model `belongs_to` `Game` model, then it means that `platforms` table in your database should have a column named `game_id`, and it should store the `id` of the game to which it belongs.

But you have done otherwise. You have place the column in your `Game` model, and that's why your association would never work.

Besides, doing `<%= @game.platform_id.system %>` doesn't make sence whatsoever. Rails gives you option to get a model from another model through the use of association.

```
<%= @platform.game %> # It makes perfect sense. Since a platform belongs_to a game
```

Comment: thank you Arslan and @pavan! I have 2 other models which `belongs_to :game` -- and those models have `game_id` in them.. not sure why I did otherwise with `Platforms`.. but will fix this right now. thank you!